# subsetting dataframe results in incorrect output

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to achieve a simple task of creating a subset of my dateframe (df) by calculating the mean from a variable with repeated measurement (measured multiple times a day, over several weeks).  This variable is called "consumption" in my df

I followed this example here, and adapted the code to my df and my desired conditions: [Calculate mean of column data based on conditions in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753162/calculate-mean-of-column-data-based-on-conditions-in-another-column?noredirect=1&lq=1)

However, I went and calculated a few of the means by hand (using excel), and just get completely different results

Could someone point me in the right direction of where my code is going wrong?

I do have "0" as a few measurements, and they are important, and need to me included when calculating mean.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
df <- read.table("https://pastebin.com/raw/Zpa8cLBN", header = T)
```

```
library(dplyr)
```

```
df_mean <- df %>% group_by(treatment,day,Control) %>% summarise(
  consumption = first(consumption), consumption = last(consumption), consumption = mean(consumption[consumption >= 0]))
```

```
desired_results <- read.table("https://pastebin.com/raw/vZten0jd", header = T) # calculated manually in excel
```

When I compare the two, the results in the column "consumption", which should be the calculated mean, are not correct at all.

Thanks everyone

Comment: You need to use different variable names in your `summarise`, because here you are modifying `consumption` each time you call it

Comment: Hello

Thanks for the tip.  I will post it as a response.  I didn't realize using the same variable name would cause this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that I need to use variables names for the `summerise`function that are different than the original `df`

```
df_mean <- df %>% group_by(treatment,day,Control) %>% summarise(
  Mean_consumption = first(consumption), Mean_consumption = last(consumption), Mean_consumption = mean(consumption[consumption >= 0]))
```

When cross referenced with my `desired_results`, it's what I was looking for.

Thanks @jlesuffleur

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Mean_consumption = first(consumption), Mean_consumptionlast = last(consumption), Mean_consumptionfilt = mean(consumption[consumption >= 0])), .(treatment, day, Control)]
```

Comment: Hello

Thanks for the comment.  I appreciate the input